# Matrix of a Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\psi$ be a linear operator on $V$, a vector space of dimension two. How do I show, given $\psi$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity, that there is a $v$ such that {$v$,$\psi$(v)$} forms a basis, and further how do I write the transformation as a matrix with respect to that matrix? For the matrix, the first column would be 0,1, but I don't know what the second column would be.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation here seems to be: let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ [not necessarily finite-dimensional!], and let $\psi: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on $V$.  Then exactly one of the following occurs:

(i) There is $\lambda \in F$ such that $\psi(v) = \lambda v$ for all $v \in V$.
(ii) There is $v \in V$ such that $\psi(v)$ is not in the span of $v$.

It is clear that the conditions are mutually exclusive.  Seeking a contradiction we suppose that neither (i) nor (ii) holds.  Then there are $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ in $F$ and $v_1,v_2 \in V$ with $\psi(v_1) = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $\psi(v_2) = \lambda_2 v_2$.  Observe that $v_1$ and $v_2$ must be linearly independent.  Let $v = v_1 + v_2$.  Then $\psi(v) = \psi(v_1) + \psi(v_2) = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2$.  Now suppose there is $\lambda_3 \in F$ such that

$\lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 = \psi(v) = \lambda_3 v = \lambda_3 v_1 + \lambda_3 v_2$,

so

$(\lambda_1 -\lambda_3)v_1 = (\lambda_3 - \lambda_2) v_2$.

Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, this equation forces $\lambda_1= \lambda_3 = \lambda_2$.  This is a contradiction.

In other words, the only endomorphisms which preserve every one-dimensional subspace are the scalar linear transformations.  The OP's first question is a special case of this.

As for the second question: yes, the first column of the matrix is $(0,1)$.  In fact the second column of the matrix could be *anything* whatsoever: since $\psi(v)$ is linearly indpendent from $v$, for any $w \in V$ (here I am assuming, as the OP is, that $V$ is two-dimensional) there is a unique linear transformation $v$ such that $v \mapsto \psi(v)$ and $\psi(v) \mapsto w$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\phi\neq0$, so there's a vector $w\neq0$ s.t. $\phi(w)\neq0$.  If $w$ is not parallel to $\phi(w)$ we're done.

Otherwise $\phi$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda\neq0$ with multiplicity $1$: as the multiplicity was $2$ then $\phi$ is a multiple of the identity.  Thus the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$ must have another zero $\lambda'\neq\lambda$. Now we'll proceed in Betty's way: there exists $w'\neq0$ s.t. $\phi(v')=\lambda'v'$.  Now show for $v:=w+w'$ that $v\neq0$ and $v$ is not parallel to $\phi(v)$.

*Edit*: The proof can be simplified as follows. The characteristic polynomial of $\psi$ can't possess a double zero as $\psi\neq \mathrm{id}$.  If $\psi$ has no eigenvalue, any $v\neq0$ will serve.  Otherwise define $v$ to be the sum of two eigenvectors of the different eigenvalues.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a v such that
$\psi(v)$ is not a multiple of v, and not zero; (1)
and then you have your basis.

Is there such a v?  There must be a v such that $\psi(v) \ne 0$ (v is not in the nullspace of $\psi$) or else $\psi$ is identically 0.  We will assume this is not the case.

So let v be any vector which is not in the nullspace of $\psi$. There are two cases:

I) v is not an eigenvector of $\psi;$ that is $ \psi(v) \ne \lambda v$.  Then this v  satisfies (1).

II) v is an eigenvector of $\psi$.  Let u be any other non-zero vector which is not a multiple of v.  There must be such a u because this is a 2 dimensional space.  Let w = av + bu where a,b are not zero.

First, $\psi(w) \ne 0$ because $\psi(v) = a\lambda v \ne 0$.  Next, there must be a choice of a and b such that w is not an eigenvector of $\psi$; if a particular choice of a,b, causes w to be an eigenvector, choose a different b. Then av + bu cannot be a multiple of w; and it cannot be a multiple of v.  Since there are at most two eigenvectors in a 2 dimensional space, w cannot be one.

Then w and $\psi (w)$ are independent and w satisfies (1).

Comment: Why is $\psi$ doomed to have eigenvectors?

Comment: In a finite dimensional space every linear operator has at least one eigenvalue (that's a theorem). I think the proof I offered you is a bit complicated, and suggested a simpler one in my edit of my answer.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ has which eigenvalue?

Comment: eigenvalue = 1 eigenvectors a(0,1)

Comment: So $\lambda=1$ is a solution of $\lambda^2+1=0$?

Comment: You are not right again: take $\phi=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, but $(v,\phi(v))$ is not a basis.

Comment: First re the $\lambda$ I did indeed lose a - sign.  The eigenvalues are $\pm i$.  I worked out the eigenvector for $\lambda = i$ as (1+i,1-i).  This is a complex vector, which is not a problem for you.  The theorem with proof that every square matrix must have an eigenvector can be found in "Linear Algebra and its Applications" by Peter Lax.  In case you don't know, Lax is one of the pre-eminent mathematicians of 20th century.

Comment: Second, an v in the nullspace of M  will not work.  However, your problem said, "there exists a v", not "for every v".  You chose a bad v, and of course it didn't work.  Choose a v which is not in the nullspace of your matrix and which is not an eigenvector, and you will be fine.

Comment: Third, there is a rule here that we are to treat everyone with respect. "You are not right again" is very poor language to use, especially if someone is trying to help you.  Your implication is that I must not know what I am talking about; you also sound like you are having a ball showing me I am wrong; when more accurately I am tired and overworked so I make mistakes.  That does not mean I know nothing.  However, even if I were a complete idiot, you can respond in a respectful way.  "I don't think your char. equation is right, what did you use" gets the point across fine.

Comment: Betty, by no means I wanted to offend in any way.  If I did, please apologize.  But now to your comments: *in general* a $2\times 2$-matrix doesn't possess eigenvalues.  I'm pretty sure that Lax refers to finite-dimensional complex vector spaces. -- To that nullspace thing: $\psi=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$; here $\lambda=1$ and we chose $w=(1,0)^t$ and $\lambda'=0$ so we take $w'(0,1)^t$. (Note that $w'$ is in the null space of $\psi$, please.) now define $v=w+w'=(1,1)^t$, thus $(v,\psi(v))=\bigl((1,1)^t,(0,1)^t\bigr)$. -- Personally, I don't answer questions here if I'm overworked

Comment: And to be honest: I was astonished about the series of your mistakes.  Not being a native speaker I've chosen the phrase: “You are not right again.” -- by the literal translation of that phrase into German no German speaking human being would be offended. -- As mathematicians we are obligated to be exact and true, as humans we are doomed to sometimes commit errors. And as humans living in the world at the same time we have the duty to help each other.  So don't consider me to be a pervert that has fun to put you in a bad light, please.  Not you, Betty, was wrong, only some of your statements.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  Thank you for your apology and explanation.  Re not having eigenvalues, the hypothesis is that we are in a 2 dimensional space, so I think we do indeed have eigenvalues for all 2x2 matrices.  I'm well aware we may not in an infinite dim space. If I only get on this site when I am not overworked that is never.  I have just a little free time and I use some of it here.

Comment: I do make many mistakes, partly because I studied math very long ago and have forgotten a lot, partly because I am tired and partly because I'm good on concepts and poor on details.  I would rather keep trying and learn something than give up because of my errors.  I'm am not really a mathematician so perhaps I do not have such an obligation to be exact and true.  Anyway, thanks for your teaching.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I lost my editing time on the first note.  Wanted to say that I see I claimed 2 eigenvectors, which does not need to be the case.   I should have said that v should not be an eigenvector and not in the nullspace.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Just another thought.  You asked "why is $\psi$ doomed to have eigenvalues?"  No doubt this is a translation but the usual usage would be something like "required to have" or "why must $\psi$ have ..."  "Doomed to have" has connotations -- it sounds like a college student making a joke. "Doomed" implies some kind of awful fate, like execution. I will make a point to remember in the future that not everyone is a native English speaker. I am sure if I tried to write in German it would be hilarious and/or all wrong.